# how to get string from jtable with null cell

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have jtable and the data from mysql. 
In mysql I have a column that allowed for null (it's called 'fil').
When i retrive the data to jtable, it's OK.
Then, I want to fill the jtextarea and enable the button if the 'fil' is not null by click the jtable row.
Here my code:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
String num = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
String sub = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
String desc = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2).toString();
String start = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3).toString();
String end = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
String sta = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 5).toString();
String fil = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
if (fil != "") {
  jButton1.setEnabled(true);
  jButton1.setToolTipText(fil);
} else {
  jButton1.setEnabled(false);
  jButton1.setToolTipText("");
}
jTextArea1.setText("Subject: " + sub + "\n" + "Description: " + "\n" + desc + "\n" + "From " + start + " to " + end + "\n" + "Status: " + sta);

jLabel3.setText(num);
```

the problem is when I clicked the row with null 'fil', the program give the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: `// TODO add your handling code here:` This adds **nothing** to our understanding of the problem and is therefore noise. 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). HArd code some data in the source code, to replace the DB. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: At what line you got this error?

Comment: @YAS_Bangamuwage in this code, in line "String fil = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6).toString();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (fil != "") {
```

should be:

```
if (fil != null) {
```

Edit:

```
String fil = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
```

You can't invoke toString() on a null object so you need something like:

```
Object filObject = jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6);
String fil = (filObject == null) ? "" : filObject.toString();
```

Then you would use your original test:

```
If (fil != "")
```

Comment: In the future tell us the statement causing the NPE. See edit for my next guess. If it doesn't help, well you have already been asked to post an `MCVE`.